# CONSTANT_MethodHandle_info and CONSTANT_MethodType_info

Tags: java, jvm

In what situation can **Java 7** compiler generate `CONSTANT_MethodHandle_info` and `CONSTANT_MethodType_info` constant pool entries?. Is it possible? Or they are completly used only with `invokedynamic` instruction and therefore never generated by **Java 7** compliant compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**javac 7** does not generate these entries. But you know, JVM is not only for Java language. For example, **groovy** compiler may generate JDK 7 compatible bytecode that has **invokedynamic** and the corresponding constant pool entries.